# C I believe my child process dies too quick to run my signal?

Tags: c, process

Got a bit of a weird situation here that I thought I'd solved using a alarm signal. I have a parent that forks for a child. Now in this child process, I want it to recognise "SIGTSTP" signal which is catching control + z.

To prevent the child from dying straight away, I placed in a alarm(5) signal to keep it running a bit longer. The child also has the call for the Control + Z SIGNAL. The problem I'm facing is, when I get to the run time of that particular code after compiling it, I press control Z and I get the result from the handler as expected however I also get on terminal :

```
[9]+ Stopped ./a.out
```

I can't seem to press control Z again though as nothing seems to work...eventually the alarm expires and the code just finishes execution? If I placed my handler for control Z in the parent process it all runs fine.

```
fork2 = fork();

    if (fork2 < 0)
    {
      write(2, "CHILD B FORK ERROR. \n", 21);
    }
    else if (fork2 == 0)
    {
      signal(SIGALRM, handleSignal);
          if (signal(SIGTSTP, handleSignal) == SIG_ERR)
        {
          write(2, "Error catching signal Z \n", 26);
        }
      write(1, "I am child of B \n", 17);

      alarm(5);
    }
    else
    {
        // where parent code is
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead of [siganl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html)?

Comment: I would prefer to use that, been told I have to use signal or I would loose more marks.....stupid really.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how [alarm(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) works. Alarm is not a blocking call and will not keep your child process alive longer. I suggest you use [sleep(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep) instead, sleep blocks for x seconds or until a signal arrives that is not ignored. I would write it something like this (untested, uncompiled code):

```
fork2 = fork();

if (fork2 < 0)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "CHILD B FORK ERROR.\n");
}
else if (fork2 == 0)
{
  if (signal(SIGTSTP, handleSignal) == SIG_ERR)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error catching signal Z\n");
  }
  fprintf(stdout, "I am child of B \n");

  while(sleep(5) == 0);
}
else
{
    // where parent code is
}
```

I kept it pretty close to your sample, but I replaced the "write" calls by fprintf and added a while loop that checks if "sleep" returned a non-zero value (==> a signal interrupted the sleep). If I would write this code myself I would also not use signal(2), but sigaction(2).

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a shot with sleep. wouldn't fprintf write to a file

Comment: No luck, took out the alarm and replaced with sleep but still facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't know what you have in your handleSignal function ofcourse. But if you catch the SIGTSTP signal, the normal functionality of that signal is overridden. This means that the child process will NOT be stopped by the ctrl+z. The "[9]+ Stopped ./a.out" message you see if from the parent process being stopped.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in the child process by using the handler?